# Determine winner

Tags: php

`print_r($scores);`

```
Array ( [Player 1] => 39 [Player 2] => 39  [Player 3] => 39 )
```

Lets say there are a variable amount of players in this array. What is the simplest way to calculate a winner or tie game?

Comment: Do you want to sort the array or what? We need to know the ruls of the game to decide a winner.

Comment: High score winner, players with the highest (and equal) scores win.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Determine the winning score, then get all players with the winning score:

```
$max_score = max($scores);
$winners = array_keys($scores, $max_score);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort the array in reverse order:

```
arsort($scores);
```

arsort will sort the array in reverse order and maintain index associations. I am supposing that the winner will have most point, if it's the one with less points use instead asort().

The winner will be in position 0, ties will be in successive positions, if they have the same amount of points of the winner.

Comment: This addresses the tie score question as well: store value 0 and then step through until value n != value 0. All players with value 0 are ties, if there's only one player in the group, its a clear win.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest:

Use sort: http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php

```
$sorted_array = asort($scores);
```

The first item has the slowest score.

Or use arsort, which sorts the other way round

```
$sorted_array = arsort($scores);
```

The first item has the highest score.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php